# Como faço uma pesquisa para encontrar quais arquivos possui determinada palavra?

Tags: git, github

Caso de uso: estou navegando em um projeto, tentando entender o codigo. São vários arquivos diferentes de código. Estou analisando um destes arquivos e ele chama uma função abc().

Como eu faço para, via web, saber quais arquivos do projeto utilizam (e onde está a definição) desta função abc()?

(assim como eh possível com o find no linux)

Comment: Via web acha difícil... mas vc pode baixar o projeto e usar uma IDE para dar um "find all"

Comment: o que você pode fazer é na tela do projeto você pode apertar a letra "T" e depois escrever o que procura, mas é só para o nome dos arquivos

Comment: obrigado @hugocsl, mas a ideia eh não precisar baixar. Como estou aprendendo, gosto de fuçar nos projetos pelo site do github mesmo e ir tentando entender o código, mas sem a necessidade de baixar

Comment: obrigado @Bulfaitelo, mas a ideia eh pesquisar dentro dos arquivos, não o nome deles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a busca do próprio GitHub, no canto superior esquerdo, selecionando para buscar no seu repositório.

Mas como o pessoal respondeu aqui, talvez seja melhor clonar localmente e selecionar. Para achar a definição, vários editores utilizam o atalho ctrl + clique na função.

Comment: obrigado, era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Não sei se é exatamente do que precisa, mas você pode usar o `Ctrl + L` para fazer uma busca por uma palavra-chave ou parte dela.

Selecione `Ctrl + L` e digite `função abc()`, vai mostrar o local exato do termo pesquisado.